# Пузырьковая сортировка на С++

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, c++

Приведите пример пузырьковой сортировки на С++.

Comment: Например вот [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdjMKPP97m4&feature=youtu.be) есть, чувак все доступно показывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сортировка пузырьком вектора на С++

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
inline void swap( T & arg1, T & arg2)
{
    T temp = arg1;
    arg1 = arg2;
    arg2 = temp;
};
template <typename T>
void bubble_sort( std::vector<T> & vArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vArray.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = vArray.size()-1; j > i; --j)
        {
            if (vArray[i] > vArray[j])
            {   swap( vArray[i], vArray[j]); }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Судя по реализации алгоритма, это вовсе не bubble_sort (не пузырьковая), а сортировка выбором.

При пузырьковой  было бы

```
// Обмен СОСЕДНИХ элементов (изменив также при этом остальной код).
swap(vArray[i], vArray[i+1])
```

Это просто предупреждение для тех, кто хочет тупо скопировать. Я уже прочитал в других темах по сортировке, где путают пузырьковую с выбором.

Comment: полностью согласен

Answer (score 1):

Обобщенная сортировка пузырьком выглядит следующим образом:

```
template<typename BidirIterator, typename Compare = std::less<>>
void bubble_sort(BidirIterator first, BidirIterator last, Compare cmp = {}) {
    if (first == last) return;
    while (first != --last)
        for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it)
            if (!cmp(*it, *std::next(it)))
                std::iter_swap(it, std::next(it));
}
```

Самые больше элементы "всплывают" в конец последовательности, по этому на каждой итерации внешнего цикла не-сортированная часть последовательности укорачивается с конца.

Comment: Для двумерного динамического массива не подойдет, потому что не всегда  динамические массивы будут располагаться друг за другом

Comment: @ARHovsepyan при чем тут двумерный динамический массив и какая разница как они расположены?