# Сортировка двумерного массива по столбцам

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема при сортировке двумерного массива по столбцам. По строках сделал, по столбцам не получается.

Должно получится что-то типа этого:

[image: Скриншот]

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сортируете все элементы матрицы (как одномерный массив), а потом заполняете из него (отсортированного одномерного массива) матрицу по столбцам (в примере - по три элемента на столбец).

Пример:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int nRow = 3;
    const int nCol = 4;
    std::vector< std::vector <int> > array = {
        {1, 3, 2, 4},
        {5, 8, 6, 7},
        {9, 12, 11, 10}
    };

    std::vector<int> oneDimensionalArray;

    for (const auto& row: array){
        for (const auto& element: row){
            oneDimensionalArray.push_back(element);
        }
    }
    std::sort(oneDimensionalArray.begin(), oneDimensionalArray.end());
    int i = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < nCol; c++){
        for (int r = 0; r < nRow; r++){
            array[r][c] = oneDimensionalArray[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < nRow; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < nCol; c++){
            std::cout << array[r][c] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
1 4 7 10 
2 5 8 11 
3 6 9 12
```

Но это исходя из примера.
Ещё вашу формулировку (не глядя на пример) можно понять как сортировка каждого столбца в отдельности, тогда по другому надо делать.

Comment: А методом пузырька можно эту сортировку сделать?

Comment: Конечно, кто вам мешает ? =) Какая разница каким методом вы отсортируете данные, если на выходе всё равно будет всё тот же самый отсортированный массив. Другое дело что сортировка пузырьком имеет сложность O(N^2), а std::sort - O(N * logN)

Comment: А можете дать код как это будет выглядеть сортировка пузырьком?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488736/286405

Answer (score 0):

легко

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
using namespace std;
int main()
{    
    const int row = 3, col = 4;
    int m[row][col] = {{1, 3, 2, 4}, {5, 8, 6, 7}, {9, 12, 11, 10}};
    std::sort(m[0], &m[row][0]);
    valarray<int> v(m[0], row * col), res(row * col);
    for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i) 
       res[slice(i , row, col)] = v[slice(i * row, row, 1)];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
         for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
             m[i][j] = res[i * col + j];
             cout << m[i][j] << ' ';
         }
         cout << endl;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

хотя если вам массив не нужен, то его можно убрать и сразу инициализировать `valarray<int> v(row * col)` и сортировать его от `&v[0]` до `&v[row * col]` , а результатом будет  `res` (а в цикле сразу выводите `res[i * col + j]`), и код будет короче...

Comment: Оно по строках сорт.

Comment: ах да, добавлю сейчас