# Отсортировать массив символов по алфавиту

Tags: c++

Изучаю указатели, не могу решить одну из задач

#include

```
using namespace std;

void bsort(char**);
void order(char* , char* );

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    char* arrch[7];
    int dec = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        arrch[j] = new char;
        cin >> arrch[j];
    }
    cout << "Не отсортированный список\n";
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        cout << arrch[j] << endl;
    bsort(arrch);
    cout << "Отсортированный список\n";
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        cout << arrch[j] << endl;
    cout << "Результат\n";
    return 0;
}
void bsort(char** arg)
{
    int j, k;
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        for (k = j + 1; k < 7; k++)
            order(*(arg + j), *(arg + k));
}
void order(char* arg, char* arg1)
{
    for (int j = 0; (*(arg + j) && *(arg1 + j)) != 0; j++)
    {
        int a = (int)*(arg + j); int b = (int)*(arg1 + j);
        if ((a - b) > 0)
        {
            char* temp = arg;
            arg = arg1;
            arg1 = temp;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно написать свою функцию сортировки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала словами говорите что должно произойти, а потом напишите все сказанное в виде кода.

Во первых символы имеют свое целочисленное значение, и они прекрасно сравниваются, поэтому их не нужно преобразовать в тип `int` для сравнения.

Дальше попробуйте вставить код функции `order` в место вызова этой функции в  `bsort` и старайтесь представлять что получится...

Если же у вас ничего не вышло, то посмотрите как [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/145/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A1)сделано(примеров сортировки полно по интернету). 
P.S. спросите у себя зачем нужно передавать в `bsort` указатель на указатель. Не облегчит вам и читабельности вашей программы, передачи просто указателья на начало?...